# Facebook Graph API giving different results on different values for limit parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an application that GETs posts, comments and likes. All using a non-blocked App and using good access_tokens and all. However, it seems the Facebook API gives different results when using different limit values but that just doesn't make sense.

For my testing, I use a post from a president candidate that has over 20,000 comments when I check on Facebook.

When I do:
/POSTID/comments?**limit=500**
and follow all the paging queries the API returns, it returns about **14,000 comments**.

When I do:
/POSTID/comments?**limit=400**
and follow all the paging queries the API returns, it returns about **11,000 comments**.

When I do:
/POSTID/comments?limit=**20000**
and follow all the paging queries the API returns, it returns about **9,000 comments**.

Also, it looks like when I use offset parameter I get LESS total comments than when I use since parameter (using  the timestamp of last retrieved comment).

I know some comments may be unavailable because of privacy stuff, but my desire is simple: I want ALL public comments... How can I make sure I get them if even the limit parameter gives me back different results?

Comment: Yes this happens often when fetching comments, especially when there are many comments. Since the number of results are stable for any fixed value of 'limit', I'm convinced this is not random brittleness but more likely filtering; maybe spam/abuse or other.